# how convert column data into row

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is a pic of my table a need convert date column in header in my view of codeigniter and want to show that on a date student present/absent.

[image]

I want to format the data like this:

```
|DATE/NAME|  12/11/16  | 13/11/16  | 14/11/16  | 15/11/16  | 16/11/16  |  
|Lokesh   |  HD        | HD        | HD        | HD        | HD        |
|LLLL     |  HD        | HD        | HD        | HD        | HD        |
|LLLLLL   |  HD        | HD        | HD        | HD        | HD        |
```

Comment: I guess, you should format your question.

Comment: well have you **tried** anything yourself so far? if yes: please share it with us. if no: *try* something yourself first, then share it with us.

Comment: i don't have any solution please help i am new in codeing

Comment: But this is not a free code development service... this is an incredibly common need and there are many examples already. Try some reasearch. Then try.

Answer (score 0):

You should use foreach statement. You're a newbie, so I'm helping you but please try to do something before asking for help next time. Also please learn PHP before Codeigniter.

Edit: It looks like you want to group by dates, so please check [Codeigniter guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) and edit my code for it.

Your code should be like below:

Model:

```
public function some_model_function()
{
  $data = array();

  foreach ($this->db->get('your_table_name')->result_array() as $row)
  {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  return $data;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function some_controller_function()
{
  $data['some_name'] = $this->Your_model_name->some_model_function();
  $this->load->view('your_view_name', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Column Name 1</td>
      <td>Column Name 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($some_name as $r) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r['key_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r['other_key_name']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```